# Firebase onMessageReceived not called when app in foreground

Tags: php, android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have read much documents regarding firebase push notification behaviour clearly. I'm able to see notification on the system tray when my app is in background but not triggering `onMessageReceived`call back when app is in foreground. I can see the logs that the message is received on my app. I have tried calling with data payload and without data payload from app server. My app server is using php script to trigger the fcm apis. Following is the php script I'm using

```
  $url = 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send';
  $fields = array(
            'registration_ids' => $registatoin_ids,
     'notification' => array( "title"=>$title, "body" => $notification_message ,"click_action"  => $click_action,'color' => "#74BCEE",'icon' => "school_logo"));
      $headers = array(
            'Authorization: key='xxxxxxxxx',
            'Content-Type: application/json'
        );

        // Open connection
        $ch = curl_init();

        //echo "here";exit;
        // Set the url, number of POST vars, POST data
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

        // Disabling SSL Certificate support temporarly
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($fields));

        // Execute post
        $result = curl_exec($ch);
        if ($result === FALSE) {
            //die('Curl failed: ' . curl_error($ch));
            curl_close($ch);
            return;

        }
        print_r($result);
```

Following are the services i'm using in my Android app

```
    <service
    android:name="service.MyFirebaseMessagingService">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
    </intent-filter>
</service>

<service
    android:name="service.MyFirebaseInstanceIdService">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT" />
    </intent-filter>
</service>
```

Comment: When you say that you tried with data payload do you mean that you replaced the `notification` field with `data` in your JSON in the PHP code? And even with that your onMessageReceived method is not being called when your app is in foreground?

Comment: I suspect that the issue is in your AndroidManifest.xml.
try replacing "service.MyFirebaseInstanceIdService" with ".service.MyFirebaseInstanceIdService" (note the dot at the beginning).
See section "android:name" in https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/service-element.html

Comment: @GeorgeLBA I tried sending with notification and data payload together. In both with and without data payload cases  onMessageReceived is not called when app is in foreground. I can see the logs that the message is received inside FirebaseMessagingService

Comment: @DiegoGiorgini I have restructured the package names to single folders, so that I can directly use service. in Manifest file.

Comment: what do you mean? names have to start with "." if they are relative to the package name, or the should contain the full package name

Comment: @DiegoGiorgini My project folder structure is not like main->java->com->appname it is java->activites, java->service. So in this case I can point package name wihtout "." since it is not inside root folder. The services working fine otherwise I should have not got the fcm token or background messages. Thanks for the comment

Comment: Maybe adding you FirebaseMessagingService to the question would assist.

Comment: By Firebase docs https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options
Notification messages are delivered to the notification tray when the app is in the background. For apps in the foreground, messages are handled by callback onMessageReceived() on Android. The notification key in the data bundle contains the notification.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem. My problem was that the `<service></service>`
tags were outside the `<application></application>` tag in the manifest file. When I put in the `<application></application>` tag, the problem was solved.

Comment: That fixed it for me. Thanks @Jamal

Comment: I was really getting crazy about that, checked application many time, switched to different emulators. But thanks that you saved my day.

Comment: Life saver. wish I had found this earlier.